# How can you get the size of a file in an archive using TrueZip?

Tags: java, truezip

As per the TrueZip docs, it appears that the `length()` method returns 0 or -1.
I am updating a WAR archive and I would like to only update files whose lengths have changed. How can this be achieved?

Thanks in advance,

Martin

Comment: You have a link to the relevant documentation?  Have you tried anything?

Comment: Well, `compareTo` and `equals` are not what I'm looking for. I have the javadocs locally (downloaded as Maven dependencies). Both methods compare the paths instead of the contents/sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, call the method `TFile.umount()` to commit any changes.

Then use the following method to obtain a TFile which does not detect the archive file and call its length() method:

```
private static TFile newNonArchiveFile(TFile file) {
    return new TFile(file.getParentFile(), file.getName(), TArchiveDetector.NULL);
}
```

Comment: Actually, this is now easier. Starting with TrueZIP 7.5, you can just call TFile.toNonArchiveFile().