# how to get file size in truzip

Tags: java, truezip

I am using truezip version (7.7.9) to update a archive file.
The way I am doing it is as follows

```
File entry = new TFile(filepath);
writer = new TFileWriter(entry);
writer.append("MyString");
writer.flush();
long fileSize = entry.length(); // which always gives value as 0
```

I need the exact file size for some purpose
But this always gives 0
Is there any other way I can get that.

I read the documentation of TFile class\

https://truezip.java.net/apidocs/de/schlichtherle/truezip/file/TFile.html#length()

couldn't quite understand what it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://truezip.java.net/faq.html):

> Every now and then you might want to treat an archive file like a
>   regular file rather than a virtual directory. For example, when trying
>   to obtain the length of the archive file in bytes. You would normally
>   do this by calling the method File.length(). **However, if the File
>   object is an instance of the TFile class and the path has been
>   detected to name a valid archive file, then this method would always
>   return zero. This is because you might have changed the archive file
>   and then it would be impossible to return a precise result until the
>   changes have been committed to the target archive file.**

It seems you can either compute the size of the file before changing it and then add the size of what you are appending, or you need to write the file and then call `File.length()`. You can do this by calling [TVFS.unmount()](https://truezip.java.net/apidocs/de/schlichtherle/truezip/file/TVFS.html#umount()) or [TVFS.unmount(TFile)](https://truezip.java.net/apidocs/de/schlichtherle/truezip/file/TVFS.html#umount(de.schlichtherle.truezip.file.TFile))

Answer (score 1):

See this article at official page

[The API should not detect an individual archive file as a virtual directory. How can I do this](https://truezip.java.net/faq.html#ignoreArchiveFile)

Look at this

> [...]
>   However, if the *File* object is an instance of the *TFile* class and the path has been detected to name a valid archive file, then this method would always return zero. This is because you might have changed the archive file and then it would be impossible to return a precise result until the changes have been committed to the target archive file..

It also applies on **TPath**

I wonder if you can use *Files.size(path)* in order to get what you need (after & before changes on your TZip)

Hope It will help.

Answer (score 1):

If the archive file is valid, then it returns 0. If there is any problem occurs then it will give IOException.

If you change anything, then you need to call the method `TFile.umount()` to commit all changes.

Then use the following method to obtain a TFile which does not detect the archive file and call its `length()` method:

In `TrueZIP 7.5`, you can just call `TFile.toNonArchiveFile()`

```
// Note that the actual path may refer to anything, even a nested archive file.
TFile inner = new TFile("outer.zip/inner.zip");
TFile file = inner.toNonArchiveFile(); // convert - since TrueZIP 7.5
... // there may be some I/O here
TVFS.umount(inner); // unmount potential archive file
// Now you can safely do any I/O to $file.
long length = file.length();
```

---

You can do it by another way also:

```
private static TFile newNonArchiveFile(TFile file) {
    return new TFile(file.getParentFile(), file.getName(), TArchiveDetector.NULL);
}
```

Resource Link:
[How can you get the size of a file in an archive using TrueZip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874112/how-can-you-get-the-size-of-a-file-in-an-archive-using-truezip?rq=1)